# Function with 0 arguments - void vs void*?

Tags: c++, syntax, void, function-declaration, function-definition

I know that you can declare a function without any arguments simply like this:

```
void test()
{
    cout << "Hello world!!" << endl;
}
```

But I have also seen

```
void test(void)
{
    cout << "Hello world!!" << endl;
}
```

and

```
void test(void*)
{
    cout << "Hello world!!" << endl;
}
```

My question is: What is the difference between using `void` and `void*` here?

Comment: I don't ever recall seeing the last one. I expect it will require you passing a pointer to any type.

Comment: `test()` and `test(void)` are equivalent in C++, but not in C. Unless C compatibility is required, the [former form should be preferred](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl25-dont-use-void-as-an-argument-type). The function `test(void*)` differs from the other two; it takes an unnamed argument of type  `void*`.

Comment: `void` is “nothing”, `void*` is “the location of something”. There’s a big difference between nothing at all and a place.

Comment: There's also this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822654/foovoid-vs-foovoid

Comment: Then shouldn't void* be "the location of nothing"?

Comment: No.  `void*` is essentially a typeless pointer, a raw memory address.  It can point to any "object."  You can set it to `null` to have it point to nothing.

Comment: @super, Perhaps, but that's not how it turned out. I don't see how it would justify its existence with that meaning, so it probably provided a lucrative opportunity to reuse syntax.

Comment: `void f(void)` is a C-ism. In C++ you don't need that and wouldn't normally do that. You'd just do `void f()`.

Comment: @super Like many other things in C and C++, the word “void” means different things depending on context. On its own it means “nothing”, with an added asterisk it means “anything”. (There’s loads of fun when you get to “static” and “operator”.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the difference between using `void` and `void*` here?

When the argument type is `void`, the function must be called without any arguments.

When the argument type is `void*`, the function must be called with an argument that is a `void*` or can be converted to a `void*`.

`void` stands for "nothing" but `void*` does not stand for "pointer to nothing". In fact, it's quite the contrary. `void*` stands for pointer to anything except `void`. It is oxymoronic but that's how the language defines those two.

Comment: Why is it like this?

Comment: `test(void)` is for C compatibility. C needs this for backward compatiiblity with early versions of C that didn't have parameter types in the argument list.

Comment: Related to the void pointer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530080/what-is-a-void-pointer-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530080/what-is-a-void-pointer-in-c)

Comment: 'oxymoronic' - Made my day.

Answer (score 7):

The one an only form for a function with no parameters in C++ should be

```
void test();
```

---

The form:

```
void test(void)
```

That is how you define a function with no parameters in [c](/questions/tagged/c). But in C++ use this form **only** for interfacing with [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
extern "C"
{
void test(void);
}
```

---

This form:

```
void test(void*)
```

Is **not** a function with no arguments. It has an argument of type `void*` that is unnamed. It expects a `void*` pointer when called.

Have a look here for an explanation of what a `void*` pointer is: [What does void* mean and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 4):

In C++ these two declarations of a function

```
void test();
```

and

```
void test(void);
```

are equivalent and mean that the function does not take any arguments.

In C, the first function declaration declares a function with an empty identifier list, and the second function declaration declares a function with a parameter type list that in fact has no parameters.

According to the C Standard (6.9.1 Function definitions):

> 5 If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the declaration of
> each parameter shall include an identifier, **except for the special
> case of a parameter list consisting of a single parameter of type
> void, in which case there shall not be an identifier. No declaration
> list shall follow.**

This declaration of the function (that is also its definition)

```
void test(void*)
{
    //...
}
```

has 1 parameter, an object of type `void *` (pay attention to that pointers are always complete types), that is not used within the function.

This declaration is valid in C++, and is not valid in C, because in C each function parameter in a function declaration with a parameter type list that is at the same time its definition shall have an identifier, except in the case when a `void` parameter is used, as specified in the quote above.

In C you may use such a declaration only when the declaration is not at the same type its definition.

So in C for example you may write like

```
void test(void*); // declaratipon
```

and then

```
void test( void *ptr ) // declaration and definition
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: "has 1 parameter, an object of type void * "  -- it's not necessarily an object

Comment: @nicomp pointers are objects. For example in C object is defined like "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
values"

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: What is the difference between using void and void* here?

`(void)` parameter list is same as empty parameter list. The `void` here does nothing in C++ and is unnecessary unless compatibility with C is needed - see the second part of the answer.

`(void*)` does not accept 0 arguments. It accepts 1 argument. The type of the parameter is `void*` which is a pointer type.

---

> Why is it like this?

Because of backwards compatibility with C. In C, `(void)` is the only way to declare a function that only accepts empty argument list. `()` parameter list declares any function without specifying the parameters. The number of parameters could be any, including 0. The use of `()` parameter list in C is becoming an obsolete feature.

Quote from C11 standard draft N1548:

> Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function.  An empty list  in  a  function  declarator  that  is  part  of  a  definition  of  that  function  specifies  that  the function  has  no  parameters.  The  empty  list  in  a  function  declarator  that  is  not  part  of  a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

> Future language directions
>
> Function declarators
>
> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.
>
> Function definitions
>
> The  use  of  function  definitions  with  separate  parameter  identifier  and  declaration  lists (not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

C is this way because of backward compatibility with older versions (pre-standard) of C where parameter lists weren't declared.

Comment: *"() parameter list declares a function that accepts any number of arguments"* could you please expand on that "`()`"

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It's a leftover from K&R C, where you didn't declare the arguments of a function in the parameter list.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added language rules to expand on it.