# How to pass void pointer by reference

Tags: c, pointers, void, mmap

I want to have a `void*` as a function parameter and then inside a function modify that pointer (change it to `NULL`).

Code below doesn't change `memory1` to `null` after function call. How can I change that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void myFree(void**freeMemoryPointer){
    /*some code*/
    *freeMemoryPointer=NULL;
}


int main(){
    void *memory1 = mmap(NULL, getpagesize() , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);//example
    printf("\nCurrent pointer: %p\n", memory1);
    myFree(memory1);
    printf("\nShould show null: %p\n", memory1);
}
```

I've also tried this and it works:

```
myFree((void*)&memory1);
```

However I need to set `void*` as a function parameter and not `(void*)&void*`.

Comment: myFree(&memory1) should work

Comment: also main() is not a valid signature for main: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108208/5878272

Comment: C does not have built-in reference types; `(void*)&void*` would not be a valid parameter type. Are you compiling as C++ or C? Write the code using `void myFree(void**freeMemoryPointer)` as the function declaration and `myFree(&memory1);` as the call. If that does not work, make a [mre] showing it and edit it into the question.

Comment: @Fredrik: `int main() {…}` is a valid definition of `main`. C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1 says `main` shall be declared as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` “or equivalent,” and `int main() { … }` is equivalent. In a function declaration that is not a declaration, `()` does not declare parameters or their types (including not declaring there are no parameters). However, in the grammar for a function definition, in C 2018 6.9.1, `int main() { … }` defines the function to take no parameters, making it equivalent to `int main(void) { … }`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil isn't the form of an empty parameter list deprected though?

Comment: @Fredrik: No, it is not deprecated, and that would be a separate question from whether it is valid. It is obsolescent, which means it is currently a feature but could be considered for withdrawal in the future.

Comment: @EricPostpischil here is a respone from you on the matter https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167747/5878272

Comment: @Fredrik: Yes, so? That answer and my comments above are correct. The feature is obsolescent and valid, is not deprecated, and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil fair enough, I always thought it was deprecated but I was wrong :)

Comment: cant reproduce  https://godbolt.org/z/fPxfY1YEP https://godbolt.org/z/8razoT9MT

Answer (score 2):

As the question is stated, this is not possible in C.

Passing the value of the pointer `memory1` passes a copy of the pointer. The function may use that to access whatever `memory1` is pointing at, but it has no way of changing `memory1` itself. To do that, the function will need a pointer to `memory1`, i.e. `&memory1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the pointer to the pointer to modify it.

```
void myFree(void**freeMemoryPointer){
    /*some code*/
    *freeMemoryPointer=NULL;
}


int main(void){
    void *memory1 = mmap(NULL, getpagesize() , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);//example
    printf("\nCurrent pointer: %p\n", memory1);
    myFree(&memory1);
    printf("\nShould show null: %p\n", memory1);
}
```

Compiles without warning and executes correctly in C & C++ ( https://godbolt.org/z/fPxfY1YEP https://godbolt.org/z/8razoT9MT)