# Old C code Notation for a Function that Returns a Function Pointer

Tags: c, function, arguments

I am looking at some late 80's C code. I have the following definition.

```
void (*_flush())(){ /* body ommitted */ }
```

I believe this is a function, `_flush` , with `void` as its argument list and returns a function pointer that returns `void` and has `void` as its argument list.

The equivalent in two parts:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void);
functptr flush(void){  /* body ommitted */ }
```

Do I understand the old notation correctly?

Comment: cdecl.org  ......................

Comment: ... yes you got it right.  Do you want someone to explain how this is exactly interrupted or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is (almost) correct:

```
cdecl> explain void (*_flush())()
declare _flush as function returning pointer to function returning void
```

It's not correct to say that your function has `void` as its argument list, though.  A function like:

```
void func()
```

Doesn't take *no* arguments, it takes an *unspecified number* of arguments.  You could call it in whichever of these ways is appropriate:

```
func()
func(a);
func(a, b, c);
```

and so on.  If the *implementation* of `_flush` doesn't make use of any parameters, you can probably safely use `void` as you suggest, but your example doesn't include enough information to say.

A good reference: [C function with no parameters behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929711/c-function-with-no-parameters-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.cdecl.org/ to get an nice translation of your function.

```
void (*_flush())()
declare _flush as function returning pointer to function returning void
```

Had the definition of function `_flush()` used any parameters itself, they would have been listed between the last `)` and `{` so we can be confident that the function `_flush` takes no arguments.

```
void (*_flush())() { /* body omitted */ }
//----------------^
```

The return value of `flush` is itself a function, let's call it `foo`

```
void foo(...)
declare foo as function returning void
```

Here it is known that the function returns `void`, but its parameter list could be of any number of parameters and of any number of any type.  Just not known from the info given but likely discernible from the body of `_flush`.