# Accessing the parameters passed to a function with an empty parameter list in C

Tags: c, ansi-c, kr-c

Since functions with empty parameter lists can be passed a variable number of parameters in C,
Suppose I have a function defined as :

```
void foo(){
// I want to access the parameters passed in here
}
```

And I call it with arguments, say

```
foo(1,2,3);
```

Is it possible for me to get a hold of the values of those passed arguments inside my foo() function? I'm hoping for something along the lines of **$_ , the default variable in Perl.**

EDIT: The kind of behavior im expecting is like the one depicted in this question : [C function with no parameters behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929711/c-function-with-no-parameters-behavior)

Comment: That's not how `$_` works in Perl, and I'm pretty sure that function call has undefined behavior.

Comment: Are looking for variadic functions?

Comment: The question you linked to contains this comment: "*@John it means the compiler will not check number (or type) of arguments, but you must nevertheless call the function with arguments matching the parameters in the definition.*"

Comment: @alk yep, thats what i was looking for.

Comment: The behavior depicted in the other question is infinite recursion (possibly with stack overflow). Please clarify what exactly you're talking about.

Comment: @melpomene, I cited the other question only to validate that such a call will go through even though it is an obsolescent feature. My question was if it was possible to access the arguments inside the function body in such a scenario. Instead, variadic functions seems like the right way to go about this. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

C99:

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>
> [...]
>
> 6. If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>      prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>      have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument
>      promotions*. **If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>      behavior is undefined.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Thus `foo(1,2,3)` has undefined behavior. It's not guaranteed to even enter the function body, let alone give you access to extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**undefined behavior**
Maybe you need [`Variadic Arguments`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic)