# Why don't I get a "conflicting types" error when function has no arguments?

Tags: c, function-declaration

In this example i'm getting a `Conflicting types` error as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a(int b);

int a(int *b){
 return 6;
}

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

But not in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a(int b);

int a(){
 return 6;
}

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Why the second example is compiling fine although the declaration and definition and of `a` are still different?

Comment: The definition of a says ”any number of parameters” which still is fine I guess.

Comment: also in the second example you will get a "error: redefinition of 'a'", and is because C does not support overloading (except if you compile it with a C++ compiler, which supports overloading)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C function with no parameters behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929711/c-function-with-no-parameters-behavior)

Comment: @EricPostpischil copy and paste that code and instead od declaring it, implement it, and you will see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in C (but not C++), `a()` declares a function with an unspecified number of parameters. Use `a(void)` instead.

See [C function with no parameters behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929711/c-function-with-no-parameters-behavior)

Answer (score 4):

### Overview and History

Due to the history of how the C language developed, `int a()` does not mean “`a` takes no arguments and returns an `int`.” It means “`a` takes unspecified arguments and returns an `int`.”

Since “unspecified arguments” is nominally compatible with “one argument that is an `int`,” the compiler does not give an error for conflicting types. Due to further rules in C (see “Function Compatibility” below), the types are incompatible, but the compiler is not required to diagnose this.

Originally in C, functions were declared with a parameter list of `()`, and it was up to the caller to provide the correct types. (In addition, arguments were “promoted”; `char` arguments were converted to `int`, and so on, but this is a separate issue.) Where a function was defined, it was defined with names of parameters, such as `int a(b)`, and the declarations of those parameters followed, as in:

```
int a()
int b;
{
    return 6*b;
}
```

But that was only for the definition. The declaration did not have those declarations of the parameter types.

Later, to improve the type information about functions, C added grammar for full declarations of functions including parameter types, such as `int a(int b)`. However, since the old grammar was already using `int a()` to mean “unspecified parameters,” the language had to keep that meaning to support old code.

Instead, a special form was designated to mean “no parameters,” and that is to put `void` by itself in the parameter list. `int a(void)` means “`a` is a function taking no parameters and returning `int`.” So, if you declare a function as `int a(void);` and then define it with `int a(int b) { … }`, the compiler will give you an error message.

### Function Compatibility

One of the rules for function types to be compatible in C 2018 6.7.6.3 15 says:

> … If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters,…

The declaration `int a(int b);` has a parameter type list with one parameter.

This definition:

```
int a(){
 return 6;
}
```

has an empty identifier list and, between the `int a()` and the `{`, defines no parameters. So they do not agree in the number of parameters. However, the compiler is not required to diagnose this incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Second example:

`int a(){`
`a` is a function taking **unspecified** number of parameters. So any number is fine and thus no error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compiler defect.

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 15. ...**If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified
>       by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier
>       list, both shall agree in the number of parameters**, and the type of
>       each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that
>       results from the application of the default argument promotions to the
>       type of the corresponding identifier

So as in these declarations

```
int a(int b);

int a(){
 return 6;
}
```

the number of parameters differs for the functions the compiler shall issue a message because the name `a` is used to declare two different functions.

For example running this code using gcc 8.3 you can get the following errors

```
prog.c: In function ‘a’:
prog.c:5:1: error: number of arguments doesn’t match prototype
 int a(){
 ^~~
prog.c:3:5: error: prototype declaration
 int a(int b);
     ^
```